# xamarin forms ios camera crash issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin forms cross platform application. In that application i am using a xamarin forms dependency service to take photo from iOS and android device on native platform. Android camera working fine but iOS camera giving error and app crash suddenly. I log and trace issues of iOS camera as following.

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'

Following are my iOS native code used to take photo and it returns photo stream as result.I call this method or service from my shared xamarin form project using dependency service.

```
public Task<CameraResult> TakePictureAsync(bool cameraFlag)   {    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CameraResult>();


Camera.TakePicture(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController, (imagePickerResult) =>
   {
    if (imagePickerResult == null)
    {
     tcs.TrySetResult(null);
     return;
    }
    var photo = imagePickerResult.ValueForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")) as UIImage;
    // You can get photo meta data with using the following
    // var meta = obj.ValueForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata")) as NSDictionary;
    var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string imageName = Settings.AppuserUserId + "_" + Guid.NewGuid();
    string jpgFilename = Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, imageName + ".jpg");
    NSData imgData = photo.AsJPEG();
    NSError err = null;

    if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
    {
     CameraRes
ult result = new CameraResult();
     result.Picture = ImageSource.FromStream(imgData.AsStream);
     result.FilePath = jpgFilename;
     tcs.TrySetResult(result);
    }
    else
    {
     tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(err.LocalizedDescription));
    }    });

   return tcs.Task;   }


void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;
            if (image != null)
            {
                // Convert UIImage to .NET Stream object
                CameraResult result = new CameraResult();
                NSData data = image.AsJPEG();
                result.Picture = ImageSource.FromStream(data.AsStream);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
            }
            else
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void OnImagePickerCancelled(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }
    }
```

Please share any solution for this issue and error.

Comment: You should try setting a custom breakpoint on `System.Exception` so you see which lines triggers the exception exactly.
But from the error I see, the problem is simply related to how you're presenting the view.

Comment: I am using MessagingCenter that provide by xamrin form .I am Subscribe MessagingCenter in view model and send result of action sheets to view model then open camera using above function and class.  Means  i have a button that open action sheet with options Camera and Photo Gallery then open camera or gallery using above options and action sheet is also implemented using ios native